# Type 'DataContext' is not defined

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, linq

I downloaded VS2013 Express for WebApplications

I created a Project-->Web Application

I added A Folder -->AppCode -->Added .dbml file and changed the properties

In the web.config I added the namespace and assembly

```
<add namespace="System.Data.Linq" />

<add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
```

I don't see any error in my dataclasses.designer.vb

I added System.Linq as a reference.

When I try to access it in the default.aspx.vb I am getting Type 'DataContext' is not defined.

```
Using dc1 As New TestDataClassesDataContext() 

Using dc1 As New system.data.linq.TestDataClassesDataContext()
```

Is there anything else that I need to add? Any other suggestions?

Comment: What namespace is the TestDataClassesDataContext in?

Comment: AddAccess - I tried with  NameSpace - Dot - Did nt work

Comment: `system.data.linq` shouldn't be the namespace of your generated class. It should be related to your project name.  I don't know how VB namespaces are declared, but it should be at the top of your designer file.

Comment: Did you add references of System.Data and System.Data.Linq in your project?

Comment: yes I added the references

Comment: Can you post your test data connect designer vb file?